# She was quite decent; what happened to Barris Offee?

Tags: star-wars

I mean, she is a healer and highly loyal to her master and friends. She has seen first hand the atrocities committed by the separatist forces. Even if she did not like the Jedi Order's actions, how come she goes Dark?

Comment: The real answer is that the Clone Wars writers didn't care about believably. That said, my personal theory is that Palpatine, who is quite adept at getting people to do what he wants while making them think they are doing good, had to have been involved somehow. Note that this is entirely unconfirmed, but it seems to me to be the best in-universe explanation.

Comment: "*I did it. Because I've come to realize what many people in the Republic have come to realize, that the Jedi are the ones responsible for this War. That we've so lost our way that we have become villains in this conflict, that we are the ones that should be put on trial, all of us! And my attack on the Temple was an attack on what the Jedi have become: an army fighting for the dark side, fallen from the Light that we once held so dear. This Republic is failing! It's only a matter of time.*"

Comment: She didn't turn to the Dark Side.  She explicitly says that her actions were because she believed the Jedi were turning and she wanted to prove to them that the Jedi were responsible for the war.  Pretty much everything in Valorum's quote there.  We don't see Barriss before she does this - we can assume events happened that showed her the Jedi had fallen and fueled her decision.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer exactly as you don't provide a clear frame of reference in your question, but Barriss Offee was ultimately convicted of several crimes and sentenced to jail by the Republic courts. The crimes included:

- orchestrating the [bombing of the Jedi Temple](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Barriss_Offee#Bombing_of_the_Jedi_Temple) (resulting in the deaths of Jedi, civilians, and Republic troopers.
- the murder of [Letta Turmond](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Letta_Turmond).
- coordinating and working with an enemy of the Republic: Asajj Ventress.
- Attempting to frame Ahsoka Tano for all of the above.

Upon being found guilty, Offee was remanded into Republic custody and imprisoned (I don't think it ever states where). We do not hear of her again in any canon capacity to my knowledge.

Comment: This doesn't address the question asked. OP isn't asking about her ultimate fate, but rather **the motivation** for her committing the crimes you've detailed ("*how come she goes Dark?*").

Comment: @Valorum Eh, the question asks "what happened to Barriss Offee?". While one could infer "...to make her do X" to consider it to ask a particular, different question, my answer addresses the question the way it is currently written. However, I'll consider adding a bit more info to the question when I can so that it addresses your interpretation as well.

Comment: To be honest, it looks like you've read the title only, and misunderstood it.

Answer (score 0):

She turned to the Dark Side because she felt the Order was leaning too much towards violence and wanted to stop it. In short, she became jaded and lost her mind.